# Power supply burned out, easy to install a new one?

Tags: power-supply, desktop-computer

Ok so I left my desktop pc alone, unplugged, for a couple months, and when I came back and plugged it back in, it started emitting a high pitched squealing noise, and when I pushed the power button, it wouldn't turn on.  So I opened it up, plugged it in, and tried to find the source of the squealing.  It was coming from the power supply, so I gently moved aside some cords, and sparks started flying.  So I unplug the power quick, and open up the power block to see the circuit board, and there's some fried resistors and a couple other things I didn't recognize (I'm a CS major, not EE).  So my plan was to get an identical power supply circuit board, and one by one take out the wires that were soldered to the old power supply and put them on the new on in the same spot (I know how to solder).  My questions are these:

Should this cause any problems I'm not realizing?

How can i figure out what the exact model power supply I have?

I have pics if needed.

EDIT:

http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=31250267&l=c6f7362b27&id=1451040195
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=31250268&l=ce359acf24&id=1451040195
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=31250269&l=d06a36d300&id=1451040195
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=31250270&l=da49cf4346&id=1451040195

Comment: Yes, pics please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So my plan was to get an identical power supply circuit board, and one by one take out the wires that were soldered to the old power supply and put them on the new on in the same spot

There's nothing *wrong* with this plan, per se, but I want to make sure you're aware that a whole new power supply will be several orders a magnitude simpler to install and probably not cost a lot more -- you can get a decent power supply for around $30.

Comment: not sure if I get what you're saying...$30 sounds cheap to me?  That's what I was planning on getting.  You're saying it's a good idea or...?

Comment: @marty - What he's saying is don't buy a new board, open the chassis of the power supply, and resolder the new board in.  He's saying just buy an entirely new power supply altogether.  The cost is no different and it's a lot easier to unplug the cables from the old and install the new than it is to spend an hour soldering.  EDIT: Not to mention it'll be easier to find than an appropriate board.

Comment: OOOH.  duh.  i didn't even think of that! that's why I come here. pics are coming of the board.

Comment: @marty - Are you SURE you're not an EE major? ;)

Comment: i didn't realize that it already came soldered in.

Comment: yeah i would hope i'd've known this if i was haha.

Comment: I added pics...

Comment: @marty - Power supplies are self-contained units.  You should NEVER need to crack the case on one.  Think of it like changing the battery in your car - you could screw around with the fluid levels, replace the contacts, recoat the interior wells, or you could just buy another battery.

Comment: well when i looked at it, it just had a metal casing around it, and i thought the wires going into it were soldered on when the computer was put together (its custom built), it didn't even occur to me it came like that.  also i was curious to poke around ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that it might be a good plan to get a (slightly) higher rated power supply - just in case.

Without "doing the sums" on your power consumption I can't say what you'll need, but make sure that you get one with *at least* the same rating.

Comment: I didn't realize you couldn't get "too high" a power rating.  Good to know.  And since I got it about 8 years ago I've added an extra hard drive, upgraded the video card, and added an extra dvd drive.  So that does make sense.

Comment: If you have a 300W supply say and you've added all that new kit it could well be that your were drawing too much power.

Comment: How will I know if it's compatible if I get a new one that has more power?  Are they all pretty much ok to use since it's just power?

Comment: @marty - It *should* be compatible - as you say it's just power.

Comment: is there anything in particular I need to watch for?  This is the one I have now http://cgi.ebay.com/Antec-True-380XR-380W-Power-Supply-TESTED-/150535932666#ht_3758wt_1141

Comment: @marty - not really. As long as it fits in your case you should be good to go.